# Use of markdown in loops in Jupyter notebooks

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, markdown, comments

I have a Python program (more exactly a suite of programs) which I want to add more markdown comments in order to be train/document using them. In some of them the comments would naturally be placed go inside long loops.

My understanding is that if you split the loop by inserting a markdown cell the notebook will not execute the loop, since it sees the end of the cell as being the end of an executable block.

Is there a way round this? If so then what strategies do people adopt in such circumstances. Obviously, heavy standard-format Python commenting within the code is one option, but rather seems to defeat the purpose of Jupyter particularly if the comments need to be fairly detailed.